# Error when scrapping Selenium and Firefox

Tags: django, selenium-webdriver, firefox, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I have a scrapper inside my Django project. It works on Selenium + Firefox

My Dockerfile

```
# Install geckodriver
# Copied from: https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-firefox/dockerfile
ARG GECKODRIVER_VERSION=0.26.0
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v$GECKODRIVER_VERSION/geckodriver-v$GECKODRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz \
  && rm -rf /opt/geckodriver \
  && tar -C /opt -zxf /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz \
  && rm /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz \
  && mv /opt/geckodriver /opt/geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION \
  && chmod 755 /opt/geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION \
  && ln -fs /opt/geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/geckodriver
```

Selenium container in docker-compose

```
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox:latest
    hostname: firefox
    ports:
      - "4444:4444/tcp"
    shm_size: "2gb"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I'm getting an error when I init my scrapper class

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities


class Scrapper:
    WEBDRIVER_TIMEOUT = 2
    WEBDRIVER_ARGUMENTS = (
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        "--headless",
    )

    def __init__(self, useragent=None):
        self.options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        for argument in self.WEBDRIVER_ARGUMENTS:
            self.options.add_argument(argument)
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor="http://firefox:4444/wd/hub",
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
            options=self.options,
        )
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(self.WEBDRIVER_TIMEOUT)
```

Error

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
| urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2c4df553c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I don't know how to fix it.

UPD.
How I'm getting

```
06:45:50.852 WARN [ExternalProcess$Builder.lambda$start$0] - failed to copy the output of process 168
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Comment: I think it's related to selenium version, try upgrading. it's a warning message though. been getting this within my application for a while now but it doesn't seem to impact anything.